# wp_nav_menu not appearing correctly on category page

Tags: categories, menus

this is the code i am using to call wp_nav_menu

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'container_class' => 'menu-header',
                'theme_location' => '',
                'menu_id'         => 6,
                'depth' => 4
            )
        );
?>
```

the menu appears perfect on home page and single post pages, as seen here: http://www.enkitec.com/

but when i visit a category page e.g. http://www.enkitec.com/education/
the menu items change, it seems like some menu items don't appear.

**note:** 
i have only 1 menu in dashboard and it is set as default menu

**strange thing is:** the code above is included in header.php, so it is the same on all pages, but still the results are different on category page.

*any help would be highly appreciated.*

more over i am also including the code of my theme pages:

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title><?php wp_title('-', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo is_single() ? single_post_title('', true):bloginfo('name')." - ".bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/font_kit/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-textFill-0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider')
        .after('<div id="controls">')
        .cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed:  2500,
            timeout: 5000,
            pager: '#controls',
            slideExpr: 'a'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php if (is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments')) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="custom_wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div><!--left-->
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
            </div><!--right-->
        </div><!--header-->

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="inner" id="menu">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'container_class' => 'menu-header',
                            'theme_location' => '',
                            'menu_id'         => 6,
                            'depth' => 4
                        )
                    );
                ?>
            </div><!--inner-->
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div><!--menu-->
        <div class="clear_10px"></div>

        <?php $single_cat_title = single_cat_title(); ?>
        <?php $p_title = trim(wp_title(NULL, FALSE)); ?>
        <?php $cat = get_the_category(); $c_title = trim($cat[0]->name); ?>
```

**category.php**

```
        <div id="content" class="categories">
            <div class="left border_right">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php // the_content(); ?>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

                    <div class="clear_10px border_bottom"></div>

                    <div class="meta">
                        <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>,
                        By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>.
                        Filed Under: <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                    </div><!--meta-->

                    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older posts', '')); ?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer posts &raquo;', '')); ?></div>
                    </div><!-- #nav-below -->
                    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <h2>Nothing Found</h2>
                    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Return to home page</a></p>
                    <div class="clear_10px border_bottom"></div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (is_home()) : ?>
                    <div class="check_us_out"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!--left-->

            <div class="right">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div><!--right-->
        </div><!--content-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    </div><!--custom_wrapper-->

    <div class="footer">
        <div id="custom_wrapper">
            <div class="left">
                <?php get_sidebar('footer'); ?>
            </div><!--left-->
            <div class="right">
                &copy; COPYRIGHT <?php echo date("Y"); ?>, ENKITEC, LP.
            </div><!--right-->
        </div><!--custom_wrapper-->
    </div><!--footer-->
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menu ul li ul li:has(ul)").addClass("arrow");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    /* Register a Custom Post Type (Slide) */
    add_action('init', 'slide_init');
    function slide_init() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x('Slides', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name'         => _x('Slide', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new'               => _x('Add New', 'slide'),
            'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Slide'),
            'edit_item'             => __('Edit Slide'),
            'new_item'              => __('New Slide'),
            'view_item'             => __('View Slide'),
            'search_items'          => __('Search Slides'),
            'not_found'             => __('No slides found'),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No slides found in Trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon'     => '',
            'menu_name'             => 'Slides'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'public'                => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'show_ui'               => true, 
            'show_in_menu'          => true, 
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'has_archive'           => true, 
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'menu_position'         => null,
            'supports'              => array('title', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail')
        ); 
        register_post_type('slide', $args);
    }

    /* Update Slide Messages */
    add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'slide_updated_messages');
    function slide_updated_messages($messages) {
        global $post, $post_ID;
        $messages['slide'] = array(
            0 => '',
            1 => sprintf(__('Slide updated.'), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
            3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
            4 => __('Slide updated.'),
            5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf(__('Slide restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title((int) $_GET['revision'], false)) : false,
            6 => sprintf(__('Slide published.'), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            7 => __('Slide saved.'),
            8 => sprintf(__('Slide submitted.'), esc_url(add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
            9 => sprintf(__('Slide scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. '), date_i18n(__('M j, Y @ G:i'), strtotime($post->post_date)), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            10 => sprintf(__('Slide draft updated.'), esc_url(add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
        );
        return $messages;
    }

/* Update Slide Help */
add_action('contextual_help', 'slide_help_text', 10, 3);
function slide_help_text($contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen) {
    if ('slide' == $screen->id) {
        $contextual_help =
        '<p>' . __('Things to remember when adding a slide:') . '</p>' .
        '<ul>' .
        '<li>' . __('Give the slide a title. The title will be used as the slide\'s headline.') . '</li>' .
        '<li>' . __('Attach a Featured Image to give the slide its background.') . '</li>' .
        '<li>' . __('Enter text into the Visual or HTML area. The text will appear within each slide during transitions.') . '</li>' .
        '</ul>';
    }
    elseif ('edit-slide' == $screen->id) {
        $contextual_help = '<p>' . __('A list of all slides appears below. To edit a slide, click on the slide\'s title.') . '</p>';
    }
    return $contextual_help;
}
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}


function checkFeild($a) {
    if (trim($a)==""||$a==NULL||empty($a)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '<div class="block">',
        'after_widget' => '</div><!--block-->',
        'before_title' => '<h1>',
        'after_title' => '</h1>',
    ));
}

function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header-menu'=>__('Header Menu')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');

function fix_missing_menu($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'nav_menu_item'));
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'fix_missing_menu');
?>
```

Comment: Without knowing the code you are using, it's hard to help. Also you should spend some time formatting your question properly.

Comment: i just made some edits, kindly see if its up to the standards.

Comment: I could not see problem on the page you linked to, so I thought you had solved it already. I’ll reopen the question for now. Good luck.

Comment: thank you @toscho, and the problem is not solved yet. i still see different menus on category page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call Nav Menus by `menu_id`. Rather, define an explicit `theme_location` for each place in your Theme template at which you want to include a Nav Menu, and then use that `theme_location` as the parameter passed to `wp_nav_menu()`.

In this case, you've defined a `header-menu` Theme location, so change this:

```
<?php
 wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'container_class' => 'menu-header',
            'theme_location' => '',
            'menu_id'         => 6,
            'depth' => 4
        )
    );
?>
```

...to this:

```
<?php
 wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'container_class' => 'menu-header',
            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
            'depth' => 4
        )
    );
?>
```

Also: your pasted `category.php` code omits `get_header()`. Please verify that you *are* calling `get_header()` in `category.php`.

Comment: thanks @chip-bennett, the comments you posted is very useful, but i have already solved the problem.

Comment: @ZainBaloch so: what was the solution?

Comment: the solution was similar to what you've described above. i gave theme_location to the menu and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code of both pages, on home page I can see "Menu Item" class assigned to 'LI element' while on category page it is "page item" that means your menu is working fine on home mage but on category page something went wrong and the default [fall back menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Usage_.28Showing_Default_Values.29) - 'wp_page_menu' appeared.

Try disabling the fallback by adding another parameter to array  - `'fallback_cb' => false,` and see if works.

Comment: thank you for the reply @amit, do you mean something like this: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'Menu', 'fallback_cb' => false, 'depth' => 4 ) ); ?>`
than i have already disabled fallback_cb in my header.